# Please refer book on complex numbers - especially covering equations of complex variables topic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am searching for a good book to cover topics of complex numbers. Please refer book on complex numbers - especially  covering equations of complex variables topic . Example :

If $\alpha$ is a complex constant such that $\alpha z^2 +z +\overline{\alpha} =0$ has real root then prove that $\alpha +\overline{\alpha} =1$

or any equations in cubic, quadratic etc. in complex form.

I have referred complex numbers from A to Z by Titu Andreescu but it doesn't cover this topic .

I will be greatful to you. Thanks..

Comment: for beginner like me [Schaums Series Complex Variable](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=schaum+series+complex+variables&oq=schaum+series+complex+variables&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.12239j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=schaum+series+complex+variables+filetype:pdf) helped.

Answer (score 0):

"Geometry of Complex Numbers" by  Hans Schwerdtfeger  ( inexpensive published by dover ) and "Introduction to the Geometry of Numbers" by Roland Deaux  ( this one also published by dover ) , Links: http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometry_of_Complex_Numbers.html?id=4XE2_AqxYVkC  and http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Geometry_of_Complex.html?id=PN5UAAAAYAAJ

This second doesn't seem to have much in the way of a preview, perhaps you can check Amazon or Barnes & Noble.